# Mysql Case When for different tables

Tags: mysql, case

Can we use `case` to query different tables, for example after `FROM` or `JOIN`?

My database has `post_type` which I'm going to link to other tables such as `blogs` or `photos` etc. I want to link these tables using the `post_type`. For instance if `post_type = 1`, then link with `blogs` etc.

My current query is like this:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT title 
             FROM ( CASE WHEN comments.post_type=1 THEN blogs END) p 
            WHERE comments.post_id = p.ID ) as post_title 
 FROM comments 
 JOIN .... 
ORDER BY comments.ID
```

which doesn't work. Using that sub-query, I can only get the title of the other tables I'm linking to, so is it possible to do use `CASE` in joining? Maybe like

```
LEFT JOIN (CASE WHEN post_type = 1 THEN blogs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
comments.*,
IFNULL(blogs.otherfield,IFNULL(otherthing.otherfield,IFNULL(another.otherfield,..))) AS otherfield
FROM
comments 
LEFT JOIN blogs ON comments.post_type=1 AND comments.post_id=blogs.ID
LEFT JOIN otherthing ON comments.post_type=2 AND comments.post_id=otherthing.ID
LEFT JOIN another ON comments.post_type=3 AND comments.post_id=another.ID
...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY comments.ID
```

Ofcourse this is a kludge, but the table structure makes it necessary.

Comment: what do you propose as a better structure for comments? I thought mine was quite flexible for multitype comments before getting into this problem :(